# Is there an option --use-x-height for otftotfm?

Tags: otftotfm

I am converting a font and `otftotfm` tells me:

```
otftotfm.exe: warning: font x-height and height of 'x' differ by 100%
(The height of 'x' is usually more reliable than the x-height, so I'm
using that. Or try --use-x-height or --no-use-x-height
```

However when I add `--use-x-height` to my list of arguments, I get:

```
otftotfm.exe: unrecognized option '--use-x-height'
```

And this option is also not documented in https://www.lcdf.org/type/otftotfm.1.html

So my question is, is there an option called `--use-x-height` and what am I doing wrong applying it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option name in the warning is wrong, you should use the option `--x-height=font` instead. Alternatively you can use `--x-height=x` to explicitly use the height of the `x` without showing a warning.

Comment: I added an issue to fix this in a future version: https://github.com/kohler/lcdf-typetools/issues/32